# Is it possible to let user update database only for 2 days?

Tags: php, mysql, time, block

As my title says, my question is if it is possible to let the user update the values inserted by them only for 2 days before locking them, and making it impossible to update them.

So, is there any way? I searched and searched, but was not able to find anything that explains anything close to this.

Thank you for all your answers!

What about this? Should this work? P.S. MYSQL IS OK, ITS A SCHOOL PROJECT!!!

```
$azi = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d"));
  //
  $data_publicarii = $azi->format("Y-m-d");
  //
  // se adauga cele 30 zile
  //
  $termen = 30; // zile
  //
  $azi->add(new DateInterval('P30D'));
  //
  $data_expirarii = $azi->format("Y-m-d");
  //
  if(!empty($_GET) && !empty($_GET['id']))
    $id_anunt = $_GET['id'];
  //
  if(!isset($id_anunt))
  {
    $id_anunt = 0;
  }// sfarsit IF anunt
  //
  global $anunturi;
  //
  $interogare1    = "SELECT * FROM $anunturi
                     WHERE id='$id_anunt'";
  $rezultat1      = mysql_query($interogare1)
                    or die("Promo07: Eroare la interogare <strong>$anunturi</strong>.");
  $numar_anunturi = mysql_num_rows($rezultat1);
```

Comment: add a date timestamp to each row and check it ....

Comment: I am new to php, am I supposed to know everything? If so, what is the purpose of this website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to have a "creation_date" field in your database. Fill this field whenever a user insert a new row.
Every time a user wants to update this row, just make a query similar to :

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP(ADDDATE(:creation_date, :nb_days_to_add)) > TIMESTAMP(NOW()) as isDateValid
```

to check whether the user can update desired values.

Comment: Thank you! I was not aware of timestamps. I will study a little bit more about timestamps! Thank you!